How can I add TGX Receiver bundle in my Tauri app
I'm using Tauri with SvelteKit and I want to include TGX Receiver bundle to install with my Tuari app.
Here's a quick pass on app flow:

Download and install Tuari app on our system.  This will include installation of
Mechdyne TGX Receiver (VDI client) and my Tuari App


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
